Server error There is a problem with the server configuration. Check the server logs for more information
**this is my middleware.ts
code:**
// Ref: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#advanced-usage
import { withAuth, NextRequestWithAuth } from "next-auth/middleware"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

export default withAuth(
    // `withAuth` augments your `Request` with the user's token.
    function middleware(request: NextRequestWithAuth) {
        console.log(request.nextUrl.pathname)
        // console.log("hhhhhhhhhhhh",request.nextauth.token)

            if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/studentSuccessView")
                && request.nextauth.token?.role !== "user") {
                return NextResponse.rewrite(
                    new URL("/denied", request.url)
                )
            }

        // if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/client")
        //     && request.nextauth.token?.role !== "admin"
        //     && request.nextauth.token?.role !== "manager") {
        //     return NextResponse.rewrite(
        //         new URL("/denied", request.url)
        //     )
        // }
    },
    {
        callbacks: {
            authorized: ({ token }) => !!token
        },
    }
)
// Applies next-auth only to matching routes - can be regex
// Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
export const config = { matcher: ["/studentSuccessView"] }

my nextauth options file:
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
    secret: "ZQjtTwQeyCSz2HyPb7NzvzgyIBkFNqiAfvkaAKZYc/k=",
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                username: {
                    label: "Username:",
                    type: "text",
                    placeholder: "your-cool-username"
                },
                password: {
                    label: "Password:",
                    type: "password",
                    placeholder: "your-awesome-password"
                }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                // This is where you need to retrieve user data 
                // to verify with credentials
                // Docs: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials

                const user = { id: "42", name: "admin", password: "admin123", role: "manager" }

                if (credentials?.username === user.name && credentials?.password === user.password) {
                    return user
                } else {
                    return null
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        // Ref: https://authjs.dev/guides/basics/role-based-access-control#persisting-the-role
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) token.role = user.role
            return token
        },
        // If you want to use the role in client components
        async session({ session, token }) {
            if (session?.user) session.user.role = token.role
            return session
        },
    },
    pages:{
        signIn:"/LoginForm"
    }
}

Error that I'm facing on web is :
Server error
There is a problem with the server configuration.
Check the server logs for more information
Error on terminal is :
[next-auth][error][NO_SECRET]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#no_secret
GET /api/auth/error?error=Configuration 500 in 15ms
excepting code correction and suggestable aproaches
